# overloading function template

Tags: c++, stl

While reading Overloading function template from book C++ Templates:The Complete Guide , I came across below example:

```
// maximum of two values of any type 
template <typename T> 
inline T const& max (T const& a, T const& b) 
{ 
    return a < b ? b : a; 
} 

// maximum of two pointers 
template <typename T> 
inline T* const& max (T* const& a, T* const& b) 
{ 
    return *a < *b ? b : a; 
} 

// maximum of two C-strings 
inline char const* const& max (char const* const& a, 
                               char const* const& b) 
{ 
    return std::strcmp(a,b) < 0 ? b : a; 
} 

int main () 
{ 
    int a=7; 
    int b=42; 
    ::max(a,b);      // max() for two values of type int 

    std::string s="hey"; 
    std::string t="you"; 
    ::max(s,t);      // max() for two values of type std::string 

    int* p1 = &b; 
    int* p2 = &a; 
    ::max(p1,p2);    // max() for two pointers 

    char const* s1 = "David"; 
    char const* s2 = "Nico"; 
    ::max(s1,s2);    // max() for two C-strings 
}
```

I am not getting the meaning and purpose of char const* const& used in normal max function's return type as well argument type. Even if we use char const* than also it works fine.

Comment: Passing pointers by const reference doesn't really accomplish anything.

Comment: But the example is taken directly from book.

Answer (score 0):

re

> **”**  am not getting the meaning and purpose of char const* const& used in normal max function's return type as well argument type. Even if we use char const* than also it works fine.

it may be explained in the book (then it's done for pedagogical purposes, just a bad example), or it may be plain silliness.

There's no good reason to not just use `char const* const`, or even just `char const*` if you don't care about applying guiding rules very rigorously, or just don't have such a rule for `const` on formal arguments.

---

If it is pedagogical, then notice that all three overloads have *the same form* for the formal argument type, namely `T const&`.

That can help when you want to e.g. take the address of one of them, from template code.

I mention this because the book is by Josuttis and Vandevorde (Daveed), and they very seldom if ever do silliness.

Answer (score 0):

Since you found this in the function templates and overload resolution section of the book, the point of the example is to illustrate which functions get picked for overload resolution. To drive the point home that the non-templated function is what gets considered first, no matter how well the templated functions match, they have constructed the max example for `char const* const&`. If, instead, the function signature was `char const*`, it would be serve no didactic purpose - neither templated function is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in practice it does not make sense to return a pointer by const reference.

But here it's the book's section about function template overloading, I think it's just used for fitting the definition of the function template `max` 's return value, which is a const reference as `T const&`. So the normal `max` function (for type `char const*`) 's return value should be `char const* const&`.